# Is it possible for the stock Downloads app to detect externally added/modified/deleted files?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

Assume I add (or delete, rename) a file, with a file explorer, to the download folder where the stock Android Downloads app is looking. Is there some way to have the Downloads app refresh and notice the new file, or is the app unable to detect changes to the download folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock download app is unable to detect changes to download folder. It will keep only a list that it is given for download.